# I am unable to install cv2 from pycharm package installer

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, opencv

### I am unable to install cv2. I import it to my python version using pip through my terminal but I continue to receive this error during my pycharm import. :

Collecting cv2

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2

I have tried to import and install through pip multiple times but it does not appear as an available package for download in my pycharm interpreter.

I expected the module to install once I installed and imported through pip but it is saying that the requirements are already met and that there is nothing missing in my pip.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what i have understood, you have correctly installed the python package via pip, but you are not able to use it inside PyCharm. 
This happen when you didn't select the correct Python Interpreter inside Pycharm.

In order to fix this issue, you should open PyCharm and go to:

```
Settings->Project->Project Interpreter
```

Here, you should see the current interpreter with all installed python packages. 
At the top of the window, there is a list which contains all local interpreters. 
If you find the virtualenv or the python installation in which you have installed cv2 in the list select it, otherwise, in the right corner of the window, there is a settings icon; press it and press on Add local. 
After this navigate in your computer and select the directory that contains the virtualenv or python installation in which you have installed cv2.

At this point, you should use the correct virtualenv or python installation, so should be able to import cv2 without problems.